# Javascript and JQuery - IdCeption

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var html = $("#inline_content").html();

$(html).$("#chartDIV").html('<div id="chart_div" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;"></div>');
```

Line 1: I receive the html of a div. Works fine!

Line 2: Then what I'm trying here (It doesn't work... ) is to change a element inside the var html, as it was some un-stringed (like it's inside the actual document) div.

So how is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$("#inline_content #chartDIV").html('<div id="chart_div" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;"></div>');
```

If you are not intending on manipulating the dom directly and just manipulating a clone then you must do the following.

```
var html = $("#inline_content").clone();
html.find('#chartDIV').html('<div id="chart_div" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;"></div>');
```

now the html variable contains a copy of the element with the manipulated html.

Comment: Why not selecting the element directly? it has an ID.

Comment: sure that works, but this way it is specific to the element within inline_content...  unfortunately there are sometimes multiple elements that have the same id

Comment: But i need to copy the html, and then change one of the elements...

Comment: Then you probably want [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone)